# How to use value of one variable in entire code in Java?

Tags: java

Stored Number of lines from file in "c" variable with While loop but unable to use that variable later.

I have tried with below code but it is giving error like symbol not fund on character "c" in for loop.

```
int i = 0;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
    int c = ++i;
    System.out.println("Count of records " + i +": " + c);
}

for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) {    
    System.out.println("Element at index " + j +": " + columns[j]);
}
```

Comment: The concept here is *"variable scope"*.  Variables can only be used or accessed within their scope.  The scope of local variables is always limited to the block of code in which they are defined.  A block is a region of code within curly braces.  Outside of those braces, the local variable no longer exists.  Therefore, to expand the scope of a local variable, move its definition from its block of code to the next one that is just outside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare your `c` variable outside the loop.

```
int i = 0, c = 0;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
    c = ++i;
    System.out.println("Count of records " + i +": " + c);
}
for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) {    
    System.out.println("Element at index " + j +": " + columns[j]);
}
```